# Docker Windows | x509: certificate is not valid for any names

Tags: docker, docker-compose, splunk, open-telemetry

I am pushing OTEL traces to splunk and facing below error.

```
{"kind": "exporter", "name": "splunk_hec", "error": "Post \https://prd-p-fyu1e.splunkcloud.com:8088/services/collector\: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority, but wanted to match prd-p-fyu1e.splunkcloud.com", "interval": "29.295443106s"}
```

I am using windows dockers desktop. Any pointers what is missing

Snippet of OTEL Collector exporters:

```
splunk_hec:
token: "11d4f458-XXXXX-42cd"
endpoint: "prd-p-fyu1e.splunkcloud.com:8088/services/collector"
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using [splunkhecexporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/splunkhecexporter), so disable cert verification:

```
insecure_skip_verify: true
```

Apparently, Splunk cloud doesn't use correct TLS cert from well known CA in this case.